# app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" doesn't works with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I have start working on Android material design support library, and as a newbie I have some confusions. And, need your help. :)

1) Is it possible to use `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` with LinearLayout?

2) I want a LinearLayout just below the Toolbar. I achieved it using AppBarLayout, but I want to scroll the LinearLayout not Toolbar on scrolling the content below LinearLayout. Using `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on LinearLayout doesn't works.

3) Can we use more than one AppBarLayout in CoordinatorLAyout and Toolbar in AppBarLayout?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 1 " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

after implementing SaravInfern's solution, Here is what i achieved so far...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Scroll flags won't work on any container unless that component is designed to do so. Specific components like AppBarLayout are only designed like that.

2.do you want to hide the linearlayout after scrolling and show the toolbar??

3.As far as i know it is better to have only one appbarlayout, if you use multiple appbar layout, it may lead to scrolling problems

**UPDATE 2** do like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"

            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 1 "
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 3"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 4"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 5"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 6"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView : 7"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/yourview" /> 

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Update:

This is a work around, to micmic the desired action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>             
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:context="com.example.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 1 "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 4"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 5"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 6"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView : 7"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>
   <!-- <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" /> -->



   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I want to hide the LinearLayout after scrolling not Toolbar

Comment: https://youtu.be/enWVNP3Gifg    i want something like this, the only difference is i want LinearLayout and textViews inside it and this video has a tabLayout

Comment: what is the output you get? can you share a screen shot?

Comment: using your solution LinearLayout scrolls Up But toolBar also scrolls up and hide,

Comment: did you add this attribute `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` in your toolbar ?? this is attribute which pins the toolbar when appbarlayout is collapsed,[refer here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Comment: yes i have added **app:layout_collapseMode="pin"** in toolBar

Comment: so, even with the attribute the toolbar is hiding? add scroll flags to your collapsingtoolbar `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` this should do the trick

Comment: yes, now this works... toolBar sticks on top, BUT toolBar overlaps LinearLayout , if i add   'android:layout_marginTop="70dp"' to LinearLayout then it looks good but is this right way to do this....

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of the layout ?? and dont forget to accept the answer if it was useful..

Answer (score 4):

this code gives exactly the same output as i want...

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

         <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 1 " />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView : 7" />

</LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Before scrolling...

[image]

after Scrolling RecyclerView ...

[image]